# How to import data from another package

Tags: r

I have one package (say `testpackage1`) which contains a method called `readData()`.

This method reads a `test.data.rda` file that is placed in the data folder of `testpackage1` and after some operations, returns a data frame.

This is the only R file in `testpackage1`:

```
#' Reads data and transforms it
#'
#' @return a data.frame
#' @export
#'
#' @examples my.df <- readData()
readData <- function() {
  return(subset(test.data, x < 50))
}

initPackage <- function() {
  test.data <- data.frame(x = seq(1, 100),
                          y = seq(101, 200))
  devtools::use_data(test.data, overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

Calling the `initPackage` method creates the data frame and saves it as a .rda file in the data folder.

Now I have created a second package named `testpackage2`, that also has only one R file:

```
#' Gets the data
#'
#' @import testpackage1
#' @export
#'
#' @examples hello()
hello <- function() {
  print(testpackage1::readData())
}
```

I built both packages, then started a fresh R session and typed:

```
> library(testpackage2)
> hello()
```

But I have this error:

```
Error in subset(test.data, x < 50) : object 'test.data' not found 
4. subset(test.data, x < 50) at hello.R#8
3. testpackage1::readData() 
2. print(testpackage1::readData()) at hello.R#8
1. hello()
```

If I type `require(testpackage1)` before calling method `hello()`, then it works.

But I thought loading `testpackage2` would have automatically loaded its dependencies. I could add `require(testpackage1)` in the `hello()` function, but it seems redundant with the `@import` statement.

Moreover, the `readData()` IS correctly imported, why not the data? Should I somehow export the data as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is a bug or a feature, but I made it work by changing the `readData()` method in `testpackage1` as follows:

```
#' Reads data and transforms it
#'
#' @return a data.frame
#' @export
#'
#' @examples my.df <- readData
readData <- function() {
  return(subset(testpackage1::test.data, x < 50))
}
```

Note the `testpackage1::test.data`